# Change Wine Title

Tags: linux, wine, title-bar

This is a really silly and stupid question, but is there a way to change the text of the titlebar for a Wine window (or any window for that matter)?  It's sort of bugging me that it says "Default - Wine desktop" instead of the name of the game I'm playing.

Comment: If it's *really* a 'silly and stupid question', do I bother to read any further? On the other hand, it's a short question. I might read it anyway. [Hint: I don't think this is a good way way of starting off a question]

Answer (score 5):

There is a registry key for it:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Wine/Explorer
```

Change Desktop key value to `TITLE`, then go into Desktops and rename the key name `default` to `TITLE`.

Comment: I think it may be simple to create a .reg file to easily run it just before the application/game. Into Desktops may be tricky tho as it has the desktop WxH.

Answer (score 0):

Many KDE applications have the parameters **--caption** and **--title**. For example, using Kwrite:

```
kwrite --caption "Cake"
```

caption will have the titlebar read **Unititled — Cake**

```
kwrite --title "Cake"
```

will read just **Cake**

Comment: What does this have to do with Wine?

Comment: Your question included the text "or any window for that matter", in parenthesis. Which I took to mean, any window.

Comment: I meant any as in a method to change any application's title.

Comment: You question is not clear on that point. You can avoid the whole issue by unchecking "Emulate a virtual desktop" option in the Graphics tab of winecfg and let apps use your X window manager.

Comment: Which doesn't work in a lot of programs.

Comment: Guess it just depends what you use.

Answer (score 0):

`$ wine explorer /desktop=TITLE YourApplication.exe`

Another way can be setting `WM_NAME` in `.desktop` file, but not sure *(don't have a DE to try)*.

Generally, I think for most applications wine should allow updates of the window title from the application.